# Как получить количество подключенных клиентов в комнате

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

функция `var clients = io.sockets.clients(room);` не работают в моей версии ^1.4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Весь интернет перерыл, официальную документацию, ничего не нашел, но случайно получилось вот так :

```js
namespace.in(room).clients(function(err, clients) {
  console.log(clients.length);
});
```